# Writing a Jest test for an async function throwing an error fails

Tags: promise, jestjs

I am trying to test a function that throws an error asyncronously, but jest is not catching it

```
    async function fn() {
      await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000))
        throw new Error('some error')
      })
    };

    await expect(fn()).rejects.toThrowError('some error');
```

jest errors out

```
 ● execSeries › throws error and terminates early if a command errors

    some error

      68 |       await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      69 |         await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000))
    > 70 |         throw new Error('some error')
         |               ^
      71 |       })
      72 |     };
```

Comment: can you post your jest code?

Comment: What do you mean? That is the jest code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to get it to work with `throw` syntax but if I change it to reject the promise it works...

```
    async function fn() {
      await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000))
        rej('some error')
      })
    };

    await expect(fn()).rejects.toThrowError('some error');
```

Downside is that if there is a throw inside sub functions this won't work unless I catch it on top and rethrow it

```
    async function fn() {
      await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        try {
           await somethingThatThrowsError;
        } catch (e) {
           rej(e)
        }
      })
    };

    await expect(fn()).rejects.toThrowError('some error');
```